# Merging Pickle file with another document - Memory Error

Tags: python, merge, pickle

I'm trying to merge corpus data which is in a pickle format with a document that I have that contains passages from articles.

I have more than enough memory on my instance

However I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "summarize.py", line 112, in <module>
 data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]
 File "summarize.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]
MemoryError

Code

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Load corpus data used to train the TF-IDF Transformer
data = pickle.load(open('data.pkl', 'rb'))

# Load the document you wish to summarize
title = ''
document = ''

cleaned_document = clean_document(document)
doc = remove_stop_words(cleaned_document)

# Merge corpus data and new document data
data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]
train_data = set(data + [doc])
```

Any ideas on what is causing this or how I may overcome it?

The error is at cleaned_document = ...

Comment: By "more than enough" do you mean a few mutltiples of your data or thousands? This pseudo-code isn't enough to really guess... but its easy to have multiple copies of the data. In your real code, do `cleaned_document` and `doc` hold copies of the data? If your memory is tight, try `del` on larger items you don't need any more.

Comment: I mean I have more than a 100GB of memory available

Comment: ...and your data is much smaller than that? Are you using a 32 bit python build?

Comment: My pkl file is larger than my own document which im merging with

Comment: I'm using a 64 bit machine and python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you reach `data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]` , I don't think it's from using pickle.

```
File "summarize.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]
MemoryError
```

These lines of code seems useless, `document` is empty so `doc` is also empty.
Remove this lines for testing if the `MemoryError` persists.

```
#cleaned_document = clean_document(document)
#doc = remove_stop_words(cleaned_document)
```

Try with **not** reusing `var data`, e.g.

```
joined_data = [' '.join(document) for document in data]
train_data = set(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MemoryError` is referring to random access memory here. You're loading too much data into memory. The problem with using pickle is that it has to load the entire file into memory, so if you're pickling several large objects you can exceed the available memory. There is probably a better way of structuring your program to avoid this. Either saving the data in a format that can be incrementally read, or splitting the pickle data across multiple pickle files.